# Fetching the tags and contents of an xml document with DOM parser in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument, xmldom

Consider an XML file like this :

```
<title>sometitle</title>
<a>
    <abc>content1</abc>
    <xyz>content2</sxyz>
    <metadata>
        <b>
            <c>content3</c>
            <d><attribute></d>
        </b>
    </metadata>
</a>
```

I use this code to parse my file and i get the output such as :

**title : abc**

**a:content1 content2 content 3**

i.e it only parses the first level tags and fails to parse subtags and get the value ,any help is much appreciated since I'am a complete newbie in this.So far this is what I have tried:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load("somedoc.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;

foreach($x->childNodes AS $item) 
{
    print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: In the foreach loop, you can check if $item has child nodes

Comment: Thanks a ton Antony , that gave me so many clues since I'am learning, I executed the inner for loop but what if there are sub children within childnodes how can i know dynamically how many foreach loops to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link for php documentation on haschildnodes() functions.

You can see samples in the below page for usage.

http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks a lot Antony :) The link helped me learn a lot more!